# form validation using zend framework

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

I have been using zend framework for like three weeks...

Am currently using the `isValid($_POST)` method to validate the form, but I don't like how it shows the errors. I have been able to override the default errors already but I was looking for a way to `foreach` the whole `$_POST` array like it's done in normal php. I wanted to process the whole `$_POST` array and validate it, and if there are errors show them in a div I have created called 'errors' under the header of a page.

How to do this using zend framework?

Answer (score 1):

The function to get error messages (according you're using [InputFilters](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/fr/zend.filter.input.html)) is :

```
$form->getMessages();
```

Read this : http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/fr/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.validation